# Fresh magento 2.3 install on fresh install of centos 7 cant start install

Tags: magento2

I can't start installation from the browser. When i visit /kagneto/setup i get a 500 error.

Created permissions set per the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html). The *filesystem* user is `someuser` and has groups `someuser apache`.

```
someuser@localhost $ groups
someuser www-data
```

The following are the permissions of the directory getting the error:

```
[someuser@localhost kagento]# ls -al /var/www/html/kagento/var/
total 8
drwxrws---.  5 someuser apache   73 Jan 14 10:23 .
drwxrwx---. 14 someuser apache 4096 Jan 14 09:35 ..
drwxrws---.  3 someuser apache   36 Jan 14 10:21 composer_home
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 someuser apache  126 Jan 14 09:35 .htaccess
drwxrws---.  2 someuser apache   23 Jan 14 10:22 log
drwxrws---.  3 someuser apache   23 Jan 14 10:22 page_cache
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught kagento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException: Directory "/var/www/html/kagento/var/cache/" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:226\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(200): kagento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Driver\\File->mkdirRecursive('/var/www/html/m...', 511)\n#1 /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(93): kagento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Driver\\File->createDirectory('/var/www/html/m...', 511)\n#2 /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(294): kagento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Directory\\Write->create()\n#3 /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(132): kagento\\Framework\\App\\Cache\\Frontend\\Factory->_getBackendOptions(Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): kagento\\Framework\\App\\Cache\\Frontend\\Factory->create in /var/www/html/kagento/vendor/kagento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 226
```

While posting, i had the following stackexchange error:

> Body cannot contain "kagneto". This is a site for kagento, not an
>   X-Men character. ;-)

Replace *k* with *m* for the above. Is this a joke? I had to rename the directories just to post the output.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add your current user to the same group with apache

```
sudo usermod -aG apache someuser
```

Then

```
sudo chgrp apache /var/www/html/kagento
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /var/www/html/kagento
```

Set permission for magento project

```
cd /var/www/html/kagento
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo chmod -R 777 ./app/etc;
sudo chmod -R 777 var/;
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/static;
sudo chmod -R 777 generated;
sudo chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml;
sudo chown -R :apache .;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento;
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've done that and set permissions per docs. Output for "someuser" has groups: "someuser apache". This problem is only on CentOS7 machine. I don't have this problem doing a fresh install on Ubuntu.

Comment: "www-data" is for Ubuntu not CentOS. Looks like your reference is from a Ubuntu installation. The magento docs are correct for Ubuntu installation (different than what you posted).

Comment: @learnsomemore Updated the answer